# When do Apps script time based triggers fire

Tags: google-apps-script

[image]

> Time-driven triggers
>   A time-driven trigger (also called a clock trigger) is similar to a cron job in Unix. Time-driven triggers let scripts execute at a particular time or on a recurring interval, as frequently as every minute or as infrequently as once per month. (Note that an add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.) The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.

Do apps script triggers respect local time zone? I'm on the east coast (EST) but when I look at my logs a time based function scheduled between 8-9, has not fired (its now 10AM)

Comment: Check your container time zone and the script time zone as well - they can be different or even unset.

Comment: How do you do this?

Comment: Apps Script triggers have no built-in way to know what the time zone of the users machine is.  The trigger uses the time zone set in the Apps Script file that the function is in.  In the code editor choose the "File" menu and then Project Properties and in the "Info" tab see   "Time-Zone" setting.  If you have users in different time zones, setting the time zone to one users time zone would fix the offset problem for that user, but then cause an time offset difference for another user.  You need to know each user and their time zone and then adjust the time.

Comment: Thank you that's really helpful. I didn't know that.